# Upload audio file using AWS Lambda functions in nodejs

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-sdk-nodejs

I want to upload an audio file to s3 bucket using Lambda function but I a am not sure how to pass audio file in Lambda function event parameter so that I can take file buffer from Lambda event parameter and pass it to s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of uploading the file via Lambda function you might consider:

Upload files to the S3 directly from the browser, using AWS SDK. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html

Using Lambda to generate a singed URL, that can be used to upload a file: https://read.acloud.guru/how-to-add-file-upload-features-to-your-website-with-aws-lambda-and-s3-48bbe9b83eaa (this option is more flexible and secure).